# Loop Array - Frutas

Tags: javascript, array, loop

Estou tentando fazer um exercício, porém não foi da maneira como a plataforma queria, já perdi umas horas tentando porque sou iniciante e estou sem ideias de como resolver, poderiam me ajudar?

Enunciado:

> Um sacolão montou uma lista com as frutas que eles vendem, e de acordo com a fruta que o usuário busca eles querem informar se existe a fruta na lista ou não!
>
> ```js
> var listaDeFrutas = [ "Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"]
> ```
>
> Você deverá criar um loop que verifique se a fruta contida na variável busca existe na lista de frutas do sacolão. Se existe basta exibir uma mensagem, “Sim, temos a fruta banana disponível”. Use a variável busca para exibir o nome da fruta nessa mensagem de forma dinâmica.

O que escrevi:

```js
var listaDeFrutas = [ "Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"]
var busca = "Cajá"

//seu loop aqui

for (var i = 0; i < listaDeFrutas.length; i++ ){
    if (listaDeFrutas[i] = 3){
        
    }
}
    console.log("Sim, temos a fruta  disponível")
```

Erro:

> Você deve fazer uma condicional para verificar se o valor da fruta buscada é igual ao valor que está sendo percorrendo do array!

Comment: Os ARs esqueceram de ler **"Você deve fazer uma condional para verificar se o valor da fruta busca é igual ao valor que está sendo percorrendo do array!"**

Answer (score 3):

resolvi, rodou assim:

```js
var listaDeFrutas = [ "Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"]
var busca = "Cajá"

//seu loop aqui

for (var i = 0; i < listaDeFrutas.length; i++){
    if(listaDeFrutas[i] == busca){
        console.log("Sim, temos a fruta Cajá disponível")
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas, e se a fruta a ser buscada não for `Cajá`? Ele vai mostrar a mesma mensagem?

Comment: nocaso aí, estava procurando pelo cajá, conforme está no enunciado..

Comment: Mas, se caso `busca` fosse `"Banana"`, por exemplo, a mensagem que seria exibida (estando dessa forma) seria ainda _"Sim, temos a fruta Cajá disponível"_.

Comment: então gustavo, estou tendo as primeiras aulas, e não sei como te responder. apenas fazendo o exercicio como pediram

Comment: @GustavoSampaio, é um exercício simples que visa comparar uma variável com os itens dum vetor, nada mais.

Answer (score 2):

O meu código rodou assim:

```
var listaDeFrutas = ["Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"]
var busca = "Cajá"

for (i=0;i<listaDeFrutas.length;i++)
    if(listaDeFrutas[i]==busca){
        console.log("Sim, temos a fruta "+busca+"disponível")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O meu rodou assim

```
for (var i = 0; i < listaDeFrutas.length; i++ ) {
  if (listaDeFrutas[i] == busca) {
    console.log("Sim, temos a fruta  disponível")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz assim e deu certo

```js
var listaDeFrutas = [ "Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"]  
var busca = "Cajá"

for (var i = 0; i < listaDeFrutas.length; i++){  
    if(listaDeFrutas[i] == busca) {   
        console.log("Sim, temos a fruta " + " disponível");  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui alguns problemas considerando o enunciado do exercício:

1. Você está usando um operador de atribuição (`=`) ao invés de comparação (`==` ou `===`) para verificar se a fruta está no índice desejado;
2. Você está verificando o número `3` ao invés de verificar o conteúdo da sua variável `busca`;

Pode-se criar também uma variável de controle booleana com valor `false` para indicar se o valor foi encontrado ou não, que será utilizada posteriormente para decidir se a mensagem será mostrada. Com essas alterações temos o código a seguir:

```js
var listaDeFrutas = ["Uva", "Banana", "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"];
var busca = "Cajá";
var encontrado = false;

for (var i = 0; i < listaDeFrutas.length; i++) { // Você deverá criar um loop...
  if (listaDeFrutas[i] === busca) { // ...que verifique se a fruta contida na variável busca existe na lista de frutas do sacolão.
    encontrado = true;
  }
}

if (encontrado) { // Se existe...
  console.log(`Sim, temos a fruta ${busca} disponível`); // ...basta exibir uma mensagem. Use a variável busca para exibir o nome da fruta nessa mensagem de forma dinâmica.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe algumas operações funcionais no Array que chama-se filter e outra chamada map, você poderia utiliza-la para conseguir obter esse resultado da seguinte forma:

```
let listaDeFrutas = [ "Uva", "Banana",  "Manga", "Cajá", "Pinha"];
let search = 'Cajá';

istaDeFrutas.filter(x => x === 'Cajá').map(x => `Sim, temos a fruta ${x} disponível`);
```

Basta criar uma função com o código do filtro e usar o retorno dessa no seu console.log()

Recomendo essa leitura: https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/principios-de-programacao-funcional-com-javascript

Comment: Na realidade sua resposta não responde a pergunta, porque como o enunciado já diz, **"Você deverá criar um loop"**. Se não fosse para criar um `loop` provavelmente a melhor opção seria usar um [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ou [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains).